# Branch (branch name,branch City, Assets

Tags: mysql-workbench

create following tables with mentioned columns:branch (branch-name, branch-city, assets)
customer (customer-name, customer-street, customer-city)
account (account-number, branch-name, balance)
loan (loan-number, branch-name, amount)
depositor (customer-name, account-number)
borrower (customer-name, loan-number)
employee (employee-name, branch-name, salary).Insert 8 records in each table.then perform following queries:

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.